# Unable to run selenium tests for server running in background

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I am running my selenium server in background with the help of nssm service. I am running the server at a particular port (11111).

I wrote some unit test in VS 2010 and when I am trying to invoke the selenium service with

```
selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 11111, "*iehta", "http://www.google.co.in");
selenium.Start()
```

it gives me error "Unable to connect to the remote server". Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you telnet to that port?  This is unlikely to be a Selenium problem, but rather one related to how you're starting that server.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I verified with telnet localhost 11111 and it shows could not establish connection. However when I run th server in foreground with the command java -jar selenium-server.jar -port 11111 i am able to connect to port 11111. Any help why so?

Comment: No idea.  I've never heard of or used the nssm service.  I'd start looking there to see what the problem is.